# Is there a way to create a date or timestamp output column from a varchar

Tags: sql, presto

I have a data set with the following columns

```
time           date
1310        2020-06-01
1425        2020-06-22
1640        2020-06-29
```

My desired final output is a column in datetime format that looks as such

```
datetime
2020-06-01 13:10:00.000
2020-06-22 14:25:00.000
2020-06-29 16:40:00.000
```

I have used the following command thus far to format the output the way I would like

```
CONCAT(date_string,  ' ', substring(barstarttime, 1, 2), ':', substring(barstarttime, 3, 2), ':00.000'))
```

However, I have not had success in changing this to a datetime or timestamp.

Is there a function that can help me do so?

Thanks

Comment: See STR_TO_DATE

Comment: Why don't you store the date and time as a timestamp in the first place? Anyway, is `date` a date and `time` a string? Or are they both strings?

Comment: date is a date and time is a string

Answer (score 1):

Get the hours and minutes from the time string with `SUBSTR`. Then add the according intervals to the date.

I don't know whether Presto allows functions for the interval values. Please try:

```
select
  date + 
  interval substr(time, 1, 2) hour +
  interval substr(time, 3, 2) minute
from mytable;
```

If this doesn't work, try this instead:

```
select
  date + 
  ((interval '1' hour) * cast(substr(time, 1, 2) as integer)) +
  ((interval '1' minute) * cast(substr(time, 3, 2) as integer))
from mytable;
```

As mentioned, I don't know Presto. You may even have to cast the date to a timestamp first:

```
  cast(date as timestamp) +
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function.

```sql
select date_parse(cast(date as varchar) || ' ' || time, '%Y-%m-%d %H%i') from 
(values ('1300', date '2020-06-01')) as t(time, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below in order to convert to timestamp

```
select *,
cast(date_col as timestamp) as ts
from T
```